# Defining and using a dictionary of colours in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to define and use a dictionary of colours but I don't know how, here is my attempt:

```
my_colors = {
    "C0": "#8aceff",
    "C1": "#e35dbf",
}
fig, ax = plt.subplots (1,1, figsize =(8,6))
ax.plot(x, y0, c="C0",label=r"a")
ax.plot(x, y1, c="C1",label=r"b")
ax.legend(loc="best");
```

but it returns: `'C0' is not a valid value for color`

I think the problem is that it tries to assign "C0" directly as a colour without checking my_colors, what should I do?

Comment: `c=my_colors['C0']`?

Comment: @BigBen Wow, solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to choose a color without mentioning the name of the dictionary, which does not make sense at all.
You should use `c = my_colors['key']` in plot method.

I hope this answer has solved your problem.

Comment: Ner version of pandas do it in easy way